# google maps only loads grey box

Tags: jquery, google-maps, coldfusion, jquery-mobile

I am very new to the google maps API, but I am redirecting to different maps based on the results in a form. So my action page looks like:

```
<cfif #FORM.bar# EQ "on">
<cflocation url="http://*********/phone/barmaptest.cfm" addtoken="no"     />
</cfif>
```

The map is within jquery mobile, I am not sure if that is causing the map not to load. But when I open the page on its own the map shows up fine. But when I attempt to redirect to it it does not. I am loading the map using onLoad in the body like shown in the google maps api documentation.

Comment: how is your API key registered? If you registered the key for "yourdomain.com" and you're redirecting to "www.yourdomain.com" (or vise-versa), that could cause your issue.

Comment: Please post the code used to generate the map.

Comment: Figured out the problem, the map didn't like the JQuery Mobile ajax navigation so in the link i had to put data-ajax="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey box indicates the map is not set up correctly (meaning the map and not points of interest). Try the following:

Manually create the maps first so you can be sure you have them set up correctly. After that, you can examine the output to the browser and make sure it matches your desired outcome (tested in the first step). Any disparity between the first step and second have to be corrected and then you should have maps.

BTW, The ColdFusion code adds little to helping out the problem.

Comment: The map loads fine when I put the URL into the browser, but when it gets redirected it doesn't load. So then the question becomes why would this make a difference into how the map object is being built?

Comment: Examine the actual HTML in the browser when you redirect. That is the first spot to determining where the issue is. If there is any difference between the working and not working, in the actual source rendered by the browser, that is where you issue is. I would consider, as a test, popping up the Map in a separate browser instance and see if that works. If so, it is your redirect.